# Find boundary points of xy coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, coordinates

I have a text file with xy-coordinates called `xy.txt`.

> ```
> 29.66150677   -98.39336541
> 29.66150677   -98.39337576
> 29.66150651   -98.39336541
> 29.66150328   -98.39337576
> 29.66150677   -98.39336475
> 29.66150677   -98.39338611
> 29.66150393   -98.39338611
> 29.66150677   -98.39339646
> 29.66150659   -98.39339646
> 29.66150677   -98.39339693
> 29.66151576   -98.39334472
> 29.66151576   -98.39335506
> 29.66151511   -98.39334472
> 29.66151058   -98.39335506
> 29.66151576   -98.39334322
> 29.66151576   -98.39336541
> 29.66151576   -98.39337576
> 29.66151576   -98.39338611
> 29.66151576   -98.39339646
> 29.66151576   -98.39340681
> 29.66151067   -98.39340681
> 29.66151576   -98.39341515
> 29.66152475   -98.39332402
> 29.66152475   -98.39333437
> 29.66152443   -98.39332402
> 29.66151973   -98.39333437
> 29.66152475   -98.39332332
> 29.66152475   -98.39334472
> 29.66152475   -98.39335506
> 29.66152475   -98.39336541
> 29.66152475   -98.39337576
> 29.66152475   -98.39338611
> 29.66152475   -98.39339646
> 29.66152475   -98.39340681
> 29.66152475   -98.39341716
> 29.66151699   -98.39341716
> 29.66152475   -98.39342722
> 29.66153375   -98.39331367
> 29.66153375   -98.39332402
> 29.6615302    -98.39331367
> 29.66153375   -98.3933086
> 29.66153375   -98.39333437
> 29.66153375   -98.39334472
> 29.66153375   -98.39335506
> 29.66153375   -98.39336541
> 29.66153375   -98.39337576
> 29.66153375   -98.39338611
> 29.66153375   -98.39339646
> 29.66153375   -98.39340681
> 29.66153375   -98.39341716
> 29.66153375   -98.39342751
> 29.66152507   -98.39342751
> 29.66153375   -98.39343443
> 29.66154274   -98.39330332
> 29.66154274   -98.39331367
> 29.66153745   -98.39330332
> 29.66154274   -98.39329625
> 29.66154274   -98.39332402
> 29.66154274   -98.39333437
> 29.66154274   -98.39334472
> 29.66154274   -98.39335506
> 29.66154274   -98.39336541
> 29.66154274   -98.39337576
> 29.66154274   -98.39338611
> 29.66154274   -98.39339646
> 29.66154274   -98.39340681
> 29.66154274   -98.39341716
> 29.66154274   -98.39342751
> 29.66154274   -98.39343786
> 29.66153992   -98.39343786
> 29.66154274   -98.3934387
> 29.66155173   -98.39329297
> 29.66155173   -98.39330332
> 29.6615457    -98.39329297
> 29.66155173   -98.39328644
> 29.66155173   -98.39331367
> 29.66155173   -98.39332402
> 29.66155173   -98.39333437
> 29.66155173   -98.39334472
> 29.66155173   -98.39335506
> 29.66155173   -98.39336541
> 29.66155173   -98.39337576
> 29.66155173   -98.39338611
> 29.66155173   -98.39339646
> 29.66155173   -98.39340681
> 29.66155173   -98.39341716
> 29.66155173   -98.39342751
> 29.66155173   -98.39343786
> 29.66155173   -98.39344106
> 29.66156073   -98.39328262
> 29.66156073   -98.39329297
> 29.66155555   -98.39328262
> 29.66156073   -98.39327744
> 29.66156073   -98.39330332
> 29.66156073   -98.39331367
> 29.66156073   -98.39332402
> 29.66156073   -98.39333437
> 29.66156073   -98.39334472
> 29.66156073   -98.39335506
> 29.66156073   -98.39336541
> 29.66156073   -98.39337576
> 29.66156073   -98.39338611
> 29.66156073   -98.39339646
> 29.66156073   -98.39340681
> 29.66156073   -98.39341716
> 29.66156073   -98.39342751
> 29.66156073   -98.39343786
> 29.66156073   -98.39344196
> 29.66156972   -98.39327227
> 29.66156972   -98.39328262
> 29.66156651   -98.39327227
> 29.66156972   -98.39326964
> 29.66156972   -98.39329297
> 29.66156972   -98.39330332
> 29.66156972   -98.39331367
> 29.66156972   -98.39332402
> 29.66156972   -98.39333437
> 29.66156972   -98.39334472
> 29.66156972   -98.39335506
> 29.66156972   -98.39336541
> 29.66156972   -98.39337576
> 29.66156972   -98.39338611
> 29.66156972   -98.39339646
> 29.66156972   -98.39340681
> 29.66156972   -98.39341716
> 29.66156972   -98.39342751
> 29.66156972   -98.39343786
> 29.66156972   -98.393442
> 29.66157871   -98.39327227
> 29.66157871   -98.39328262
> 29.66157871   -98.39326327
> 29.66157871   -98.39329297
> 29.66157871   -98.39330332
> 29.66157871   -98.39331367
> 29.66157871   -98.39332402
> 29.66157871   -98.39333437
> 29.66157871   -98.39334472
> 29.66157871   -98.39335506
> 29.66157871   -98.39336541
> 29.66157871   -98.39337576
> 29.66157871   -98.39338611
> 29.66157871   -98.39339646
> 29.66157871   -98.39340681
> 29.66157871   -98.39341716
> 29.66157871   -98.39342751
> 29.66157871   -98.39343786
> 29.66157871   -98.39344084
> 29.66158771   -98.39326192
> 29.66158771   -98.39327227
> 29.66158097   -98.39326192
> 29.66158771   -98.39325788
> 29.66158771   -98.39328262
> 29.66158771   -98.39329297
> 29.66158771   -98.39330332
> 29.66158771   -98.39331367
> 29.66158771   -98.39332402
> 29.66158771   -98.39333437
> 29.66158771   -98.39334472
> 29.66158771   -98.39335506
> 29.66158771   -98.39336541
> 29.66158771   -98.39337576
> 29.66158771   -98.39338611
> 29.66158771   -98.39339646
> 29.66158771   -98.39340681
> 29.66158771   -98.39341716
> 29.66158771   -98.39342751
> 29.66158771   -98.39343786
> 29.66158771   -98.39343926
> 29.66159226   -98.39343786
> 29.6615967    -98.39326192
> 29.6615967    -98.39327227
> 29.6615967    -98.39325426
> 29.6615967    -98.39328262
> 29.6615967    -98.39329297
> 29.6615967    -98.39330332
> 29.6615967    -98.39331367
> 29.6615967    -98.39332402
> 29.6615967    -98.39333437
> 29.6615967    -98.39334472
> 29.6615967    -98.39335506
> 29.6615967    -98.39336541
> 29.6615967    -98.39337576
> 29.6615967    -98.39338611
> 29.6615967    -98.39339646
> 29.6615967    -98.39340681
> 29.6615967    -98.39341716
> 29.6615967    -98.39342751
> 29.6615967    -98.39343623
> 29.66160569   -98.39325157
> 29.66160569   -98.39326192
> 29.66160564   -98.39325157
> 29.66160569   -98.39325156
> 29.66160569   -98.39327227
> 29.66160569   -98.39328262
> 29.66160569   -98.39329297
> 29.66160569   -98.39330332
> 29.66160569   -98.39331367
> 29.66160569   -98.39332402
> 29.66160569   -98.39333437
> 29.66160569   -98.39334472
> 29.66160569   -98.39335506
> 29.66160569   -98.39336541
> 29.66160569   -98.39337576
> 29.66160569   -98.39338611
> 29.66160569   -98.39339646
> 29.66160569   -98.39340681
> 29.66160569   -98.39341716
> 29.66160569   -98.39342751
> 29.66160569   -98.39343291
> 29.66161468   -98.39325157
> 29.66161468   -98.39326192
> 29.66161468   -98.39324921
> 29.66161468   -98.39327227
> 29.66161468   -98.39328262
> 29.66161468   -98.39329297
> 29.66161468   -98.39330332
> 29.66161468   -98.39331367
> 29.66161468   -98.39332402
> 29.66161468   -98.39333437
> 29.66161468   -98.39334472
> 29.66161468   -98.39335506
> 29.66161468   -98.39336541
> 29.66161468   -98.39337576
> 29.66161468   -98.39338611
> 29.66161468   -98.39339646
> 29.66161468   -98.39340681
> 29.66161468   -98.39341716
> 29.66161468   -98.39342751
> 29.66161468   -98.39342823
> 29.66161592   -98.39342751
> 29.66162368   -98.39325157
> 29.66162368   -98.39326192
> 29.66162368   -98.39324697
> 29.66162368   -98.39327227
> 29.66162368   -98.39328262
> 29.66162368   -98.39329297
> 29.66162368   -98.39330332
> 29.66162368   -98.39331367
> 29.66162368   -98.39332402
> 29.66162368   -98.39333437
> 29.66162368   -98.39334472
> 29.66162368   -98.39335506
> 29.66162368   -98.39336541
> 29.66162368   -98.39337576
> 29.66162368   -98.39338611
> 29.66162368   -98.39339646
> 29.66162368   -98.39340681
> 29.66162368   -98.39341716
> 29.66162368   -98.39342302
> 29.66163267   -98.39325157
> 29.66163267   -98.39326192
> 29.66163267   -98.39324642
> 29.66163267   -98.39327227
> 29.66163267   -98.39328262
> 29.66163267   -98.39329297
> 29.66163267   -98.39330332
> 29.66163267   -98.39331367
> 29.66163267   -98.39332402
> 29.66163267   -98.39333437
> 29.66163267   -98.39334472
> 29.66163267   -98.39335506
> 29.66163267   -98.39336541
> 29.66163267   -98.39337576
> 29.66163267   -98.39338611
> 29.66163267   -98.39339646
> 29.66163267   -98.39340681
> 29.66163267   -98.39341716
> 29.66163267   -98.39341722
> 29.66163275   -98.39341716
> 29.66164166   -98.39325157
> 29.66164166   -98.39326192
> 29.66164166   -98.39324588
> 29.66164166   -98.39327227
> 29.66164166   -98.39328262
> 29.66164166   -98.39329297
> 29.66164166   -98.39330332
> 29.66164166   -98.39331367
> 29.66164166   -98.39332402
> 29.66164166   -98.39333437
> 29.66164166   -98.39334472
> 29.66164166   -98.39335506
> 29.66164166   -98.39336541
> 29.66164166   -98.39337576
> 29.66164166   -98.39338611
> 29.66164166   -98.39339646
> 29.66164166   -98.39340681
> 29.66164166   -98.39341103
> 29.66164749   -98.39340681
> 29.66165066   -98.39325157
> 29.66165066   -98.39326192
> 29.66165066   -98.39324533
> 29.66165066   -98.39327227
> 29.66165066   -98.39328262
> 29.66165066   -98.39329297
> 29.66165066   -98.39330332
> 29.66165066   -98.39331367
> 29.66165066   -98.39332402
> 29.66165066   -98.39333437
> 29.66165066   -98.39334472
> 29.66165066   -98.39335506
> 29.66165066   -98.39336541
> 29.66165066   -98.39337576
> 29.66165066   -98.39338611
> 29.66165066   -98.39339646
> 29.66165066   -98.39340447
> 29.66165965   -98.39325157
> 29.66165965   -98.39326192
> 29.66165965   -98.39324479
> 29.66165965   -98.39327227
> 29.66165965   -98.39328262
> 29.66165965   -98.39329297
> 29.66165965   -98.39330332
> 29.66165965   -98.39331367
> 29.66165965   -98.39332402
> 29.66165965   -98.39333437
> 29.66165965   -98.39334472
> 29.66165965   -98.39335506
> 29.66165965   -98.39336541
> 29.66165965   -98.39337576
> 29.66165965   -98.39338611
> 29.66165965   -98.39339646
> 29.66165965   -98.39339783
> 29.6616615    -98.39339646
> 29.66166864   -98.39325157
> 29.66166864   -98.39326192
> 29.66166864   -98.39324424
> 29.66166864   -98.39327227
> 29.66166864   -98.39328262
> 29.66166864   -98.39329297
> 29.66166864   -98.39330332
> 29.66166864   -98.39331367
> 29.66166864   -98.39332402
> 29.66166864   -98.39333437
> 29.66166864   -98.39334472
> 29.66166864   -98.39335506
> 29.66166864   -98.39336541
> 29.66166864   -98.39337576
> 29.66166864   -98.39338611
> 29.66166864   -98.39339119
> 29.66167552   -98.39338611
> 29.66167764   -98.39325157
> 29.66167764   -98.39326192
> 29.66167764   -98.3932437
> 29.66167764   -98.39327227
> 29.66167764   -98.39328262
> 29.66167764   -98.39329297
> 29.66167764   -98.39330332
> 29.66167764   -98.39331367
> 29.66167764   -98.39332402
> 29.66167764   -98.39333437
> 29.66167764   -98.39334472
> 29.66167764   -98.39335506
> 29.66167764   -98.39336541
> 29.66167764   -98.39337576
> 29.66167764   -98.39338455
> 29.66168663   -98.39325157
> 29.66168663   -98.39326192
> 29.66168663   -98.39324315
> 29.66168663   -98.39327227
> 29.66168663   -98.39328262
> 29.66168663   -98.39329297
> 29.66168663   -98.39330332
> 29.66168663   -98.39331367
> 29.66168663   -98.39332402
> 29.66168663   -98.39333437
> 29.66168663   -98.39334472
> 29.66168663   -98.39335506
> 29.66168663   -98.39336541
> 29.66168663   -98.39337576
> 29.66168663   -98.39337791
> 29.66168954   -98.39337576
> 29.66169562   -98.39325157
> 29.66169562   -98.39326192
> 29.66169562   -98.39324277
> 29.66169562   -98.39327227
> 29.66169562   -98.39328262
> 29.66169562   -98.39329297
> 29.66169562   -98.39330332
> 29.66169562   -98.39331367
> 29.66169562   -98.39332402
> 29.66169562   -98.39333437
> 29.66169562   -98.39334472
> 29.66169562   -98.39335506
> 29.66169562   -98.39336541
> 29.66169562   -98.39337127
> 29.66170356   -98.39336541
> 29.66170462   -98.39325157
> 29.66170462   -98.39326192
> 29.66170462   -98.39324245
> 29.66170462   -98.39327227
> 29.66170462   -98.39328262
> 29.66170462   -98.39329297
> 29.66170462   -98.39330332
> 29.66170462   -98.39331367
> 29.66170462   -98.39332402
> 29.66170462   -98.39333437
> 29.66170462   -98.39334472
> 29.66170462   -98.39335506
> 29.66170462   -98.39336463
> 29.66171361   -98.39325157
> 29.66171361   -98.39326192
> 29.66171361   -98.39324213
> 29.66171361   -98.39327227
> 29.66171361   -98.39328262
> 29.66171361   -98.39329297
> 29.66171361   -98.39330332
> 29.66171361   -98.39331367
> 29.66171361   -98.39332402
> 29.66171361   -98.39333437
> 29.66171361   -98.39334472
> 29.66171361   -98.39335506
> 29.66171361   -98.39335799
> 29.66171758   -98.39335506
> 29.6617226    -98.39325157
> 29.6617226    -98.39326192
> 29.6617226    -98.393242
> 29.6617226    -98.39327227
> 29.6617226    -98.39328262
> 29.6617226    -98.39329297
> 29.6617226    -98.39330332
> 29.6617226    -98.39331367
> 29.6617226    -98.39332402
> 29.6617226    -98.39333437
> 29.6617226    -98.39334472
> 29.6617226    -98.39335135
> 29.66173159   -98.39334472
> 29.6617316    -98.39325157
> 29.6617316    -98.39326192
> 29.6617316    -98.393242
> 29.6617316    -98.39327227
> 29.6617316    -98.39328262
> 29.6617316    -98.39329297
> 29.6617316    -98.39330332
> 29.6617316    -98.39331367
> 29.6617316    -98.39332402
> 29.6617316    -98.39333437
> 29.6617316    -98.39334471
> 29.66174059   -98.39325157
> 29.66174059   -98.39326192
> 29.66174059   -98.393242
> 29.66174059   -98.39327227
> 29.66174059   -98.39328262
> 29.66174059   -98.39329297
> 29.66174059   -98.39330332
> 29.66174059   -98.39331367
> 29.66174059   -98.39332402
> 29.66174059   -98.39333437
> 29.66174059   -98.39333807
> 29.66174561   -98.39333437
> 29.66174958   -98.39325157
> 29.66174958   -98.39326192
> 29.66174958   -98.39324293
> 29.66174958   -98.39327227
> 29.66174958   -98.39328262
> 29.66174958   -98.39329297
> 29.66174958   -98.39330332
> 29.66174958   -98.39331367
> 29.66174958   -98.39332402
> 29.66174958   -98.39333143
> 29.66175858   -98.39325157
> 29.66175858   -98.39326192
> 29.66176663   -98.39325157
> 29.66176757   -98.39326192
> 29.66175858   -98.39324585
> 29.66175858   -98.39327227
> 29.66175858   -98.39328262
> 29.66175858   -98.39329297
> 29.66175858   -98.39330332
> 29.66175858   -98.39331367
> 29.66175858   -98.39332402
> 29.66175858   -98.39332427
> 29.6617589    -98.39332402
> 29.66176757   -98.39327227
> 29.66177412   -98.39326192
> 29.66177656   -98.39327227
> 29.66176757   -98.3932525
> 29.66176757   -98.39328262
> 29.66176757   -98.39329297
> 29.66176757   -98.39330332
> 29.66176757   -98.39331367
> 29.66177543   -98.39330332
> 29.66176974   -98.39331367
> 29.66176757   -98.3933162
> 29.66177656   -98.39328262
> 29.66177775   -98.39327227
> 29.66177872   -98.39328262
> 29.66177656   -98.39326599
> 29.66177656   -98.39329297
> 29.66177855   -98.39329297
> 29.66177656   -98.39330028
> ```

I read the file using

```
import numpy as np
xy =  np.loadtxt('xy.txt')
x, y = xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1]
```

and I can plot the points with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='black', markersize=6)
plt.show()
```

Visually the data looks as follows:

[image]

I want to retrieve the xy-coordinates of the points that form the boundary of the shape. Answers on similar questions suggest to use Concave Hull. With the help of this [blog](http://chris35wills.github.io/convex_hull/) I write the following code:

```
from scipy import spatial
hull = spatial.ConvexHull(xy, incremental=False, qhull_options='Qt')
hull_indices = hull.vertices

boundary_x = []
boundary_y = []

for i in range(len(hull_indices)):
    index = hull_indices[i]
    boundary_x.append(xy[index, 0].astype('float32'))
    boundary_y.append(xy[index, 1].astype('float32'))

plt.plot(boundary_x, boundary_y, 'o', color='red', markersize=6)
plt.show()
```

The output looks like

[image]

Clearly the red points are not the boundary points. Some are enclosed by other points and they all are different from the original points. How do I define the boundary points in terms of the original points?
Please advice

Comment: Check the alpha shapes algorithm for this. https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Alpha-shape-example-in-2D-Alpha-shapes-can-be-described-as-the-shape-which-is-created-if_fig2_268345700

Comment: The **convex** hull is made of exactly the (existing) points on the boundary. Where does the notion of introducing new points come from?

Comment: I used the `scipy.spatial.ConvexHull` function and the output looks like its made from new points. Do you agree?

Comment: I can replicate the "jaggedness" of outer points, and it seems to be related to the conversion to `float32` - removing that step gives the expected, smooth hull results.  This is likely due to floating point errors in the small differences between the points.  The interior points I cannot replicate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I try to reproduce your code the convexHull function works perfectly. I changed your code so that the positions of black and red circles are rounded in the same way. And I reduced the radius of the red circles so you can better see if everything fits.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import spatial


xy = np.loadtxt('xy.txt')
x, y = xy[:, 0].astype('float64'), xy[:, 1].astype('float64')

hull = spatial.ConvexHull(xy, incremental=False, qhull_options='Qt')
hull_indices = hull.vertices

boundary_x = []
boundary_y = []

for i in range(len(hull_indices)):
    index = hull_indices[i]
    boundary_x.append(xy[index, 0].astype('float64'))
    boundary_y.append(xy[index, 1].astype('float64'))

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='black', markersize=6)
plt.plot(boundary_x, boundary_y, 'o', color='red', markersize=4)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

**Update:** If you need the concave parts of the boundary, too, you can use the python package [alphashape](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/) instead and calculate the [alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape). The points in your test data are very close, so I had to normalize the coordinates and adjust the alpha value to get reasonable results.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import alphashape


data = np.loadtxt('xy.txt')
xy = (data + [-29.0, 98.0]) * 10
x, y = xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1]
shape = alphashape.alphashape(xy, alpha=500.0)
shape_x, shape_y = shape.exterior.coords.xy

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='black', markersize=6)
plt.plot(shape_x, shape_y, 'o', color='red', markersize=4)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Importantly, the inaccuracy in the hull in the original images seems to be due to floating point errors due to the `float32` conversion - the points are all very close together and this becomes significant at that scale.  I confirm that I also cannot reproduce  the interior points.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at the code. Your answer is definitely an improvement, but I am still missing some boundary points. Especially, in the south east part of the figure. How can we include all boundary points?

Comment: @HJA24: But those points are not on the convex hull. They are (only by fractions but mathematically) on concave parts of the boundary. BTW I am using scipy version 1.7.3.

Comment: @HJA: Are you searching for a solution to get the whole boundary regardless of weather it is convex or concave?

Comment: @Markus, yes indeed. As I mentioned in the question I want to retrieve the xy-coordinates of the points that form the boundary of the shape. When looking for similar questions a lot of answers mentioned convex/concave hull so I tried that first. I found this blog (https://thehumangeo.wordpress.com/2014/05/12/drawing-boundaries-in-python/) which provides a solution, but I am struggling with the `Shapely ` points. Maybe you can take a look?

Comment: @HJA24: Yes, what you actually are looking for is [alpha shape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape). Do you need a programming example or are you fine with the tutorial you have found?

Comment: Gotcha. If you have a working Python script on my data that would be awesome and I will assign the bounty to you. The tutorial uses `Shapely`-shapes and I am having difficulty translating the used format into my data-format

Answer (score 0):

For some contours, the answer of @Markus resulted in the following error:

> WARNING:root:Singular matrix. Likely caused by all points lying in an
> N-1 space.

As a result, I tried a different solution

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon


def get_boundary(path: str) -> list:
    coordinates = np.loadtxt(path)
    x, y = coordinates[:, 0], coordinates[:, 1]
    green = Polygon(list(zip(x, y)))

    # get boundary
    boundary_x, boundary_y = green.exterior.xy
    return list(zip(boundary_x, boundary_y))

get_boundary(path=PATH)
```