# how to calculate "real area" of 2D mask in python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, 3d, shapely

I projected the 3D point cloud acquired through the depth camera onto a 2D plane.

As a result, I got a point cloud list projected on a plane like in fig1.

example Image:
[image: fig1]

**How can I get the real area of ​​a polygon made up of a point cloud projected onto a 2D plane?**

I tried to calculate the area using the shapely polygon.area function, but the function receives the coordinates of the boundary points of the polygon as input. So it failed.

(https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.Polygon.html#shapely.Polygon)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code.

Comment: The polygon you're looking for is the **convex hull** of the point set.

Comment: Try `MultiPoint(list1).convex_hull.area` or something. Sadly I only have shapely 1.8 on my computer at the moment so I can't try all the new fancy stuff from shapely 2.0

Comment: @Stef the polygon shown in the picture is clearly non-convex. See the the left and right parts.

Comment: Oops, completely right! In that case a **concave hull** or **alpha shape** would be more appropriate, but it's more complicated.

Comment: @Stef, yes there is an [alphashape](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/) package, or maybe using a Delaunay triangulation with maximum distance of the edges?

Comment: 1. triangulate (beware you have concave PCL) 2. sum up the triangle areas ...

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible numpy array with the points of the right graph?

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments.

I solved the problem through the solution provided in the url below.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72418933/find-boundary-points-of-xy-coordinates